# Volume rocker adjusts ringer volume

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have used this 
`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];` 
to give audio feedback when the device is mute but it adjusts ringer volume. I want to give audio feedback when device is in mute but it shouldnot adjust ringer volume. Please suggest.

Comment: Need more details. Do you want your audio to be silent when Silent switch is on.

Comment: I want audio to be played when silent switch is on and when volume button is pressed such that sound is audible

Comment: who and when adjusts the ringer volume ?

Comment: The following is the feedback from our QA:I can't hear any audio feedback. I heard an email notification during the
drive, so hardware functioning. Yesterday I had mute switch on during a
drive. Switched mute off during drive. Since then, no audio.
…                                                                                                                                 OK, figured it out. The volume button was turning up ringer volume, not
main audio. Shouldn't the buttons affect volume of current app?

Comment: I have to give audio feedback when ringer is silent and activated. But this fix should not affect the volume